# Using SharePoint 2013 Online, how do I run getSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser on sibling site collections and display in a single page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, site-collection

The page containing the results belongs to one of the sibling sites and I would like to be able to loop through the site collections dynamically without providing a list of collections first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the webs that are siblings of the current web you can specify the `rootWeb` of the current site then get all of its children:

```
   var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var mySite = myCtx.get_site();
   var rootWeb = mySite.get_rootWeb();
   var siblingWebs = rootWeb.get_webs();
   var web;

   //webs have a lot of information in them; suggest using an include filter
   //for production
   myCtx.load(siblingWebs);
   myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
         for (var i = 0; i < siblingWebs.get_count(); i++) {
            web = siblingWebs.itemAt(i);
            console.log(web.get_title());
          }
    }, function (sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the server relative url of the sibling site.

`http://<endpoint><serverrelativeurl of the sibling site>/_api/web/GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser(nwebtemplatefilter,nconfigurationfilter)`